# Hibernate merge with @OneToOne relation and orphanremoval set to true, with new entity not delete the old one

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I have a simple case. When I try to merge child entity witch containt new parent entity (with autogenerated id) I would like to delete old related parent entity. But it not do anything.

Child:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "child", orphanRemoval = true)
private Parent parent;
```

Parent:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
@OneToOne
private Child child;

@JoinTable(name = "parent_other_child",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "other_child_id")})
@ManyToMany(
private List<OtherChild> otherChildList;
```

Anyone knows how to manage it?

I know about workaround - with @OneToMany / @ManyToOne but I would like to avoid that if it's possible.

EDIT:

In general it works as expected (hibernate try to delete parent entity) but when Parent is related @ManyToMany to other entity (which Parent is also Owner of that relation) - it won't delete Parent - because it has still reference from relation-table.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Where is `orphanRemoval` option set?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add it to the child entity - I've just corrected it

Comment: And you want it to remove `Child` entity when removing parent one or remove `Parent` entity when removing child one?

Comment: I want to remove Parent. So if Child had Parent with id=1. And I merge that Child with new Parent with id=2 I would like to delete Parent with id=1 and add that second parent to the database.

Comment: Have you tried just invoking `em.merge()` on your `child` object? Didn't you forget about setting relationships on both sides by setters `setParent`, `setChild`? I works as expected here.

Comment: child has set parent in his structure while `em.merge(child)`. The relation is bidirectional as you can see above. Deletion on last parent and insertion of new one still doesn't work.